# deleting rejected app without deleting current version

Tags: app-store-connect

iTunes rejected the new version of my app. When I click to delete the rejected version I get the warning: "The app will be deleted from iTunes Connect and you won’t be able to use the app name or SKU again." How do I delete the rejected version without deleting the current version?

Comment: Could you please post some more details?

Comment: Why would you want to?  My understanding is you just leave it and upload the next version that has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to re-upload the new binary for review since it was rejected, right?

You do **not** have do that. In Xcode, simply upload a new binary and submit that one for review. You will be good to go.

Hope that helps :)